# Flask: same endpoints of routes

Tags: python, flask

I'm developing a Flask API and I'm having these two endpoints:

- `/length`
- `/length?morethan={value}`

How do I separate them? They are having the same beginning (before the '?') so when routing I'll have to refer to the same endpoint.

```
@app.route('/length', methods=['GET'])
def func1():
    //code

@app.route('/length', methods=['GET'])
def func2():
    value = request.args.get('morethan')
    //code
```

This code works for the second version of my API (I get what I want if I write /length?morethan=3) but for the first one I just get an empty list and it doesn't display my DB content.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you need to split the endpoint?  I'd expect to see these as a single endpoint, perhaps with an early return when no args are supplied.

Comment: Why not add a condition after 'value = request.args.get('morethan')' ?
e.g. ' if value: ... else: ...

Comment: And where should I put the condition? And what should the condition be?

Answer (score 0):

Solution found. Thanks to those who commented.

```
value = request.args.get('morethan')
if value is not None:
    //code for /tweets?morethan={value}
else:
    //code for /tweets
```